# Was there a reason Room 101 was called Room 101?

Tags: name-significance, george-orwell, nineteen-eighty-four

Was the room named after anything significant? It seems odd to me that he would name such an important piece of the novel after nothing, but maybe I am just looking too hard.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Room 101 is named after a conference room at Broadcasting House. Orwell used to sit through boring meetings there.

When it was to be demolished at the BBC, [Rachel Whiteread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rachel_Whiteread) made a plaster cast and it was displayed in the Victoria and Albert Museum, from November 2003 to June 2004.

[image: An image of a plaster cast by Rachel Whiteread of Broadcasting House.]

Sources - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ministries_of_Nineteen_Eighty-Four#Room_101), [BBC](https://web.archive.org/web/20070105132434/http://www.bbc.co.uk/bbcfour/documentaries/features/room-101.shtml), [Public Art Online](https://web.archive.org/web/20170128222559/http://www.publicartonline.org.uk/resources/reports/artistcommissions/bbc_broadcasting_house.php), [The Times](https://login.thetimes.co.uk/?gotoUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thetimes.co.uk%2Ftto%2Fnews%2Fuk%2F) (You'll need an account for The Times)